# resetForm is not a function, why do i get this error?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have a cancel button in my form page and I added

```
onClick={() => this.props.resetForm()}
```

to it to clear the form, but I get `TypeError: resetForm is not a function`

Comment: Are you passing the `resetForm` property to your component? Something like `<FormComponent resetForm={...} />`

Comment: i'm doing `export default reduxForm({
  form: "survey",
  destroyOnUnmount: false,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
  validate
})(SurveyForm);` and i think it passes thta, right?

Comment: I think the prop is not `resetForm`, but rather just `reset`.

Comment: @ChaimFriedman    but i found it here in c section https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/

Comment: I literally went through these exact same steps as you about a month ago, and after looking through our codebase, I found that we use the `reset` prop which is passed in via redux form.

Comment: @ChaimFriedman   yes, i just used that reset and it worked but my issue is that how to get that resetform work? why is it oin the doc but not working?

Comment: see this https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1208

Comment: @ChaimFriedman wow!!! it was noted at 2016 and yet they haven't taken care of it ?!!!

Comment: please add it as an answer here, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the documentation does say that in order to reset the form you should use the `resetForm` prop, as can be seen [here](https://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/faq/howtoclear.md/), the prop you actually want to use is simply `reset`.

Apparently the docs are actually out of date based on this [issue](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/1208) here.

Answer (score -1):

Formik's documentation it's wrong. You should use the `reset()` function to reset all the form values.

For example, you can do something like this using React.

```
const formRef = useRef();

const handleResetForm = () => formRef?.current?.reset()

return (
  ...
  <Formik
    innerRef={formRef}
    ...
  />
  <button onClick={handleResetForm}>Reset Form</button>
)
```